# How to add item from bottom to top after Pull refresh ListView?

Tags: android

This is my class for Print List-view in Android

```
 public class ChatActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.act_chat);
            listview = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            editMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_inputText);
            mLastSeenTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastSeenDatetextview);
            sendMsgBut = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_Send);
            recciverImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.recciverImage);
            backbutton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.contact_btnMenu);
            sendMsgBut.setOnClickListener(this);
            recciverImage.setOnClickListener(this);
            backbutton.setOnClickListener(this);    


        arrChatlist = dbHelper.fetchChatHistory(member_id, reccvierid);
            chatList.addAll(arrChatlist);
            chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(this, chatList);
            listview.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
            listview.setSelection(listview.getAdapter().getCount() - 1);
            dbHelper.updateIsRead(reccvierid);

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            switch (arg0.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_Send:
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editMsg.getText().toString()))
                    return;
                else {
                    mChatService.SendMessage(Integer.parseInt(member_id), Integer
                            .parseInt(reccvierid), editMsg.getText().toString());
                    Chat chat = new Chat();
                    chat.setMessage(editMsg.getText().toString());
                    chat.setRecieverID(reccvierid);
                    chat.setSenderID(member_id);
                    chatList.add(chat);
                    dbHelper.addMessage(chat);
                    chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    editMsg.setText("");
                    System.out.println("Messae : " + chat.getMessage());
                    listview.setSelection(listview.getAdapter().getCount() - 1);
                }
                break;



            default:
                break;
            }
        }


        // ****************************** For Location Name *********|||||||


        private class SyncStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                switch (intent.getIntExtra(BroadcastNotifier.EXTENDED_DATA_STATUS,
                        BroadcastNotifier.STATE_ACTION_COMPLETE)) {
                case BroadcastNotifier.STATE_ACTION_MESSAGE_RECEVED:
                    boolean isCurrentUser = false;
                    Chat chat = (Chat) intent
                            .getSerializableExtra(BroadcastNotifier.EXTENDED_CHAT_RECEIVED);
                    for (Datamodel model : HomeActivity.arrModel) {
                        if (("~" + model.getPhoneNumber()).equals(chat
                                .getSenderName())) {
                            chat.setSenderID(model.getId());
                            chat.setSenderName(model.getContactName());
                        }
                        if (chat.getConnectionId().equals(ConnectionId)) {
                            isCurrentUser = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (isCurrentUser) {
                        dbHelper.addMessage(chat);
                        chatList.add(chat);
                        chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        listview.setSelection(listview.getAdapter().getCount() - 1);
                    } else {
                        mChatService.createNotification(chat);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

        }


    //-------- SigNal R Method------------------------\\\
        public ChatEventHandler mChatHandler = new ChatEventHandler() {
            String previousMessage = "";
            @Override
            public void UpdateMessage(String message, String sendername,
                    long senderId) {
                if (previousMessage != message) {
                    System.out.println("new message: " + message + " sendername:"
                            + sendername);
                    Chat chat = new Chat();
                    chat.setMessage(message);
                    chat.setRecieverID(member_id);
                    chat.setSenderID("" + senderId);
                    chat.setSenderName(sendername);
                    chat.setIsUnread(false);
                    dbHelper.addMessage(chat);
                    chatList.add(chat);

                    previousMessage = message;
                    listview.setSelection(listview.getAdapter().getCount() - 1);
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        listview.setSelection(listview.getAdapter().getCount() - 1);
                    }
                });

            }


        class loadmessge extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listview.onRefreshComplete();
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
        }

    }
```

This is my XML of listview:

```
  <com.lociiapp.PullToRefreshListView
                                android:id="@+id/listView"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="150dp"
                                android:stackFromBottom="true"
                                android:transcriptMode="normal" >
```

I am able to display list-view in Android. Using chatadapter I have applied pull to refresh listview to load data 1 - 1 item in listview after refreshing but its working fine but I want to display that after refresh last item come in last in adapter and first item come in top adapter like tat way but I am unable to do that please see my screen you ll better understand what am trying to do please suggest how I will achieve.

[image].

Comment: You need to load data from last to first.For example: For(int i=arrModel.size();i>0;i--) instead of foreach

Comment: for (; i < arrChatlist.size() && i> temp + 1; i--)    i m trying top this But not item visbile in listview

Comment: For (; i > arrChatlist.size() && i> temp + 1; i--) Try this.Hope this will help to you :)

Comment: not its not working same no data is displaying in listview

Comment: make new Arraylist every time when you Add or Delete item from listview  and Sort  that Arraylist and fill that using setAdapter() everytime

Comment: Use For(int i=arrModel.size()-1;i>=0;i--) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            // loadPopupData(context, listView, emptyView,i);
            listview.setSelection(listview.getAdapter().getCount() - 1);
            listview.onRefreshComplete();

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

replace this code and Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 0):

Append your chat messages at the end of your list, or implement `getItem` to return items reversed `(length - position)`.

Looking at your code, I think the first option is the easiest:

```
public void addMessage(Chat chat) {
    values.add(values.size()-1, chat);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: that is OK but when  my last messge is Ok and second last messge is last according to that Ok should come on Bottom and last should come on top but its coming like this http://snag.gy/6quZR.jpg